# Use a variable declared in the init() from a class - Swift 4

Tags: swift, class, initialization

How can I use the variable `health` or `type` that is declared in the `init()` from my class in a function that I've created in my class?

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Boss:  SKSpriteNode {

    init(type: Int, health: Int) {

        let texture: SKTexture!

        if type == 1 {
            texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Boss1")
        }
        else if type == 2 {
            texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Boss2")
        }
        else {
            texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Boss3")
        }

        super.init(texture: texture , color: .clear, size: texture.size())
        zPosition = 2
    }

    func bossSante() -> Int {
            return health
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

//I would like to make a function that will return the value of "health"

    func bossSante()  {
        return health
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a rewrite of what you are trying to do I think.  Your design pattern needs to change.  This isn't a perfect solution, but hopefully you can modify this to your needs!

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class AbstractBoss: SKSpriteNode {
    let bossType: Int
    let bossHealth: Int

    init(externalType: Int, externalHealth: Int, texture: SKTexture) {
        bossHealth = externalHealth
        bossType   = externalType
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: texture.size())
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class BossSante: AbstractBoss {
    init() {
        super.init(externalType: 1, externalHealth: 200, texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "BossSanteImage"))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class BossDilbert: AbstractBoss {
    init() {
        super.init(externalType: 2, externalHealth: 2000, texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "BossDilbertImage"))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class BossFactory {
    func getBoss(withType bossType: Int) -> AbstractBoss {
        //Determine which boss to return here and return it!
        //Use Abstract boss in your collections and functions instead of SKSpriteNode
        switch bossType {
        case 1:
            return BossSante()
        default:
            return BossDilbert()
        }
    }
}

let bossFactory = BossFactory()
//Use AbstractBoss in containers and functions instead of SKSpriteNode
let obj: AbstractBoss = bossFactory.getBoss(withType: 1)
obj.bossHealth
```

**Summary**

- Your classes are your boss types
- Use the factory pattern to generate the proper boss

Comment: I have this error : Value of type 'SKSpriteNode' has no member 'bossSante'.
I'll edit the whole class in my post, that way you'll have an overall view.

Comment: @DarkOvis Ok I see your problem now.  I'll revise things.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to store parameters passed to your initializer as instance properties if you want access them later on.
2. You don't have to have dedicated function to get the value from class, just access the property.
3. If you want property to be immutable from outside, apply `private(set) internal` access modifier (see `type` property for example).

To sum it up:

```
class Boss: SKSpriteNode {

  private(set) var type: Int
  var health: Int

  init(type: Int, health: Int) {
    self.type = type
    self.health = health

    let texture = ...
    super.init(texture: texture , color: .clear, size: texture.size())
  }
}

let boss = Boss(type: 1, health: 100) // type and health will be stored as properties of boss
print(boss.health) // access boss' health
boss.type = 2 // won't compile since `type` becomes immutable from an external code
```

Comment: When I try the "access boss health" line, I've got this error : "Value of type 'SKSpriteNode' has no member 'health'"

Comment: @DarkOvis looks like you are storing your boss as a `SKSpriteNode` parent class, something like `var boss: SKSpriteNode`, and then `boss = Boss(type: 1, health: 100)`. In this case you'll need to cast it to the inherited class (`Boss`) like this: `(boss as? Boss)?.health` but be aware that it will return an `Int?`

Comment: Or just store it of `Boss` type: `var boss: Boss`. Since `Boss` is a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, you can use it as an instance of latter without any restrictions. And access to boss' health as an `Int` (non-optional) value.